# unable to connect to nodejs server from react client with SocketIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io, next.js

I'm learning `socketIO` and I set up and running a basic `nodejs` server . My problem is that when I try to connect to the server with my `nextJS` app nothing happens. No errors occur and the messages I want to be printed on connection do not appear .

My code :

`server.js` in backend folder

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const { v4: uuidV4 } = require('uuid');
const cors = require('cors');

const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: true,
  origins:["http://localhost:3000"]
});

app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('test',()=>{
   console.log(' i am a test') //does not appear 
  })
  
})

//I ALSO TRIED 
//io.on('test',()=>{
   //console.log('I am a test');
//})

server.listen(5000);
```

Then in my nextJS app in my frontend folder in `index.js`

```
import {useEffect} from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:5000";
const socket = io.connect(ENDPOINT);

  export default function Home() {

    useEffect(()=>{

     socket.emit('test');
    },[]);
    
   ...rest of code 
   
 }
```

So in my frontend app I emit the 'test' event to the server and the server did not console.log the response on connection

I would appreciate your help as I am new to socketIO

Comment: `"http://localhost:3000"`  is not the same as -> `"http://localhost:5000"`  You need to make sure ports are equal.

Comment: @Keith as I understand, the front-end is served on port 3000 (by a local dev server or something, like Angular-cli does on port 4200 with `ng serve`) and the back-end on port 5000

Comment: @Keith my frontend is on port 3000 and my backend on 5000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a helper function in a separate file to manage the connections, listen to events and emit events. Here is one example for same :

```
export const socketConnection = io => {
  io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("Started socket connection!");

    socket.on("message", receivedMessage => {
      console.log("Socket message received", receivedMessage);
    });

    socket.on("subscribe", async room => {
      try {
        console.log(`In room`, socket.rooms);
        await socket.join(room);
        console.log(`[socket] Room Joined Successfully : ${room}`, room);
        await io.to(room).emit("subscribeSuccess", `Subscribed successfully ${socket.id}: room - ${socket.rooms}`);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(`[socket] Error in Room Joining : ${room} : ${e}`, e);
        socket.emit("error", "couldnt perform requested action");
      }
    });

    socket.on("unsubscribe", async room => {
      try {
        await socket.leave(room);
        console.log(`[socket] Room Left Successfully : ${room}`, room);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(`[socket] Error in Room Leaving : ${room} : ${e}`, e);
        socket.emit("error", "couldnt perform requested action");
      }
    });

  });
};
```

And then in `app.js` you can import and start a socket server.

```
import { socketConnection } from "@helpers";

const io = new Server(server, {
  transports: ["websocket", "polling"],
  allowEIO3: true
});
socketConnection(io);
```

And to connect to socket from client use this :

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:5000";
const socket = io(ENDPOINT);
```

Comment: Thank you very much . I will try this later . But what changes with this approach if you have a separate file?

Comment: It's just I think is a cleaner approach to maintain socket connection and listener rather than putting everything in app.js. Great that this helped you ! Thanks : )